# How do I set the default page of my application in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7

I deployed my web application to IIS7 and everything works just fine. However, instead of typing the url of my true starting page, I want it to automatically go to www.xxxxxx.com/views/root/default.aspx.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 51):

Just go to web.config file and add following

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Path of your Page" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Besides, I had to wrap all this between <configuration> tags and set the name of my index page to the <add> tag value property, not the whole path.

Answer (score 24):

1. On IIS Manager select your page in the Sites tree.
2. Double click on configuration editor.
3. Select system.webServer/defaultDocument in the drop-down.
4. Change the "default.aspx" to the name of your document.

Answer (score 9):

Karan has posted the answer but that didn't work for me. So, I am posting what worked for me. If that didn't work then user can try this

```xml
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <defaultDocument enabled="true"> 
            <files> 
                <add value="myFile.aspx" /> 
            </files> 
        </defaultDocument> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

On IIS Manager--> Http view--> double click on Default and write the name of your desired startup page, Thats it

Answer (score 2):

For those who are newbie like me, Open IIS, expand your server name, choose sites, click on your website. On new install, it is Default web site. Click it. On the right side you have Default document option. Double click it. You will see default.htm, default.asp, index.htm etc.. to the extreme right click add. Enter the full name of your file(including extension) that you want to set it as default. click ok. Open cmd prompt as admin and reset iis. Remove all files from c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder like iisstart.html, index.html etc.

Note: This will automatically create web.config file in your c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder. I didnt have any web.config files in my inetpub or wwwroot folders. This automatically created one for me.

Next time when you enter http(s)://servername, it opens the default page you set.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like,User enter url "www.xxxxxx.com/views/root/" & default page is displayed then I guess you have to set the default/home/welcome page attribute in IIS. But if user just enters "www.xxxxxx.com" and you still want to forward to your url, then you have write a line of code in the default page to forward to your desired url. This default page should be in root directory of your application, so www.xxxxx.com will load www.xxxx.com/index.html which will redirect the user to your desired url

Answer (score 1):

I was trying do the same of making a particular file my default page, instead of directory structure.
So in IIS server I had to go to Default Document, add the page that I want to make as default and at the same time, go to the Web.config file and update the defaultDocument header with "enabled=true". This worked for me. Hopefully it helps.