# Deploy angular application on IIS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, iis-7, gulp

I am working on AngularJs application with node.js. Using gulp, I have created (compiled) my application (`app` in below image) and got the following directories

[image]

Now I completely struck how to proceed next. I want to host this application over IIS to run and see the pages (in `views` folder) but I don't know how to host it on IIS.

I tried [this](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/02/13/how-to-use-nodejs-express-and-bower-to-create-angularjs-apps.aspx) article, but it guides to use express server.

The issue is, how IIS will figure out that the first page lies in `views` folder, and even if I use the complete url

```
http://localhost:8078/views/index.html
```

it shows me all angular code with brackets like `{{logginuser}}` etc

EDIT: 
Do I need web.config file here or not. If yes then how I will define entry point to the application?

Comment: You need set as start page to you main screen (like index.html)

Comment: How can I set it in IIS?

Comment: See my answer for How can I set it in IIS? :)

Comment: far too little known about what build process you have set up in gulp. What resource paths are used when you load that url? Why are  you opening `views` directory and not root?

Comment: @charlietfl: `app` is my destination folder where gulp copies minified files. And this app is running on wampserver perfectly but I don't know how to deploy it over iis

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just have to configure a Web Application under a website in IIS and create a custom web.config.

1. In IIS, go to the Default Web Site, right-click and select Add Web Application
2. Set the Alias to be AngularApp and the Physical Path to be the root of your directory
3. Add a web.config file at the root of the directory with the following code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <defaultDocument>
           <files>
               <add value="views/index.html" />
           </files>
       </defaultDocument>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
4. Browse to your new Angular application by going to http://localhost/AngularApp (assuming http binding in IIS).

Comment: When I do this, my app breaks because it doesn't found the other resouces anymore. Any tips about it?

Answer (score 15):

Lost 2 hours with this
The solution was to go to `WINDOWS FEATURES` and check 'static content', under `COMMON HTTP` features.

[image]

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

> You need set as start page to you main screen (like index.html)

**How can I set it in IIS?**

Just go to web.config file and add following

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.html" />//Path of your Page
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

More details : [How do I set the default page of my application in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208381/how-do-i-set-the-default-page-of-my-application-in-iis7)

Comment: This is an angularJs application, and as I told that if I browse the page with complete url, it doesn't solve the angularJs conventions.

Comment: I browsed to `http://localhost:8078/views/home.html` and it showed me {{Title}}, instead of showing `Hellow World Application`.

Comment: No console error. actually the above configuration didn't work. I manually changed the url.