# deploy angular js application to IIS 7

Tags: angularjs, node.js, iis-7, gruntjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I developed a web application that uses angular js as frontend, node js and express as backend. i would like to deploy the front end code in IIS 7. I had developed this frontend code from yeomen generator and so it uses grunt for local testing and development. I have no idea how to deploy this code in IIS 7 so that it can be accessed in out intranet.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: you can use this tutorial to create an IIS server to serve static html. http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/creating-websites/scenario-build-a-static-website-on-iis

Comment: Please refer this question..     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719436/deploy-angular-application-on-iis

Comment: @Minato : Unfortunately my code is not static html. We use grunt-cli which will build the code and minify and then host the content in localhost with specified port. This task is done by grunt-cli and it takes care of live reloading and other stuffs which is very helpful for developing. But i have no idea how to deploy my code.:(

Comment: @Minato : to add to above point the html page should include npm and bower components to render in html page.

Comment: @SatheeshSaetai I think it doesn't matter whether you deploy using `grunt-cli` as long as they are static html pages. you just need to setup a webserver to serve static `.html` just tell `iis` the physical path of your content directory.. here is another good tutorial to follow http://blog.pluralsight.com/windows-server-2008-iis7