# Deploy angular 4 App in IIS

Tags: node.js, angular, iis-10

I have a multi-tenant Angular 4 and .Net core 2.0 application.

I have hosted .Net core API in IIS with deployment time debugging and for that I have followed this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/development-time-iis-support

With this configuration in IIS, I can access my API any time and if I want to debugg it, I can run it in VS.

Now, **Is it possible to run Angular app directly with IIS**. I mean is there any way that npm start will directly open app in specific IIS url like **app.myapp.local**, and not at **localhost:4200**

> what I have did so far?

- I have added one folder in **wwwroot/myapp**, and I have pointed it to Default web site in IIS.
- then, I am building my app with `ng build`, copying all content of `dist` folder to **wwwroot/myapp**.

> Is there any proper way in Angular, to handle this kind of scenario?

this question is not same as this [Deploy angular application on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719436/deploy-angular-application-on-iis)

because as I specified, **I want to start my app in debugging mode at specific URL without building it,** So please don't add it in duplicate without understanding question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy angular application on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719436/deploy-angular-application-on-iis)

Comment: You can debug a running IIS site using the Attach to Process option in VS.

Comment: @MotoSV: yes that's true, but I am looking for a way in Angular..