# Http 404 error after publishing

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

I have published a web application in asp.net using Visual Studio 2012 using web deploy... The publish was succeeded and after that when I entered localhost/Sitename in the browser it shows 404 error... What are the steps to be done in IIS to prevent this error...

Comment: Is your default page included in your project? If it's excluded, this might be the problem.

Comment: No there is no default page in the application...

Comment: What I meant was the page you're trying to reach. You work on your localhost, so there arent't any public modifiction on IIS. I'm asking you to include the page (to the project) you are trying to open on your browser. Right click >> Include To Project

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the files were actually published to the server? Sometimes files aren't published because the Build Action is set incorrectly.

If the files are there, then it could be the IIS configuration. What is your default page? If it's not Index or Default then IIS may need to be configured to load the site on the correct page

Comment: My default page is Login.aspx... I can see the application name and all the files in the IIS, but when I click on browse it redirects to this 404 not found page...

Comment: Your Default.aspx should redirect to Login.aspx, or you need to configure IIS to use Login.aspx as the default page. It won't know to do this without being configured

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this

Comment: What are the steps that are needed to be done in the IIS after publishing the web application... I have published it in Visual Studio 2012...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208381/how-do-i-set-the-default-page-of-my-application-in-iis7

Comment: Tried everything in that, but still not getting the site

Comment: What page opens when you click Browse in IIS? If you manipulate the URL to bring you to Login.aspx, does that work?

Comment: HTTp 404 Not Found Page opens...Also when I enter the Login.aspx page it still shows the above page...