# How can I define a start page in my ASP.NET website (IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I create a website in Visual Studio and I'm using IIS. But, I'd like that it show like this: localhost/app, not localhost/app/index.aspx. I've defined index.aspx as my start page in my application, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208381/how-do-i-set-the-default-page-of-my-application-in-iis7

Comment: Side note: seo-friendly urls are so much easier if you go with ASP.Net MVC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS Manager, Go to default document and Add your default page. (ex. index.aspx)

Comment: I renamed my index.aspx for default.aspx and it worked.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In your web.config

```
 <system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />               
                <add value="Login.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

or in code

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started

    Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");

}
```