# How does my ASP.NET MVC application know which view to serve?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, view

I'm trying to understand how my MVC application knows how to serve up pages. I inherited this project from someone else so I'm not entirely sure how everything works. It's an ASP.NET web application and you can see it at http://hollandandbarnes.azurewebsites.net/.

When you go to that link, the home page loads. This is served from the Home.cshtml view. But how does it know to serve the Home.cshtml view?

In the main directory, there is a default.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="default.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="umbraco.UmbracoDefault" trace="true" validateRequest="false" %>
```

...and a Global.asax file:

```
<%@ Application Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

I have three controllers in the backend, none of which serve the Home.cshtml view:

- AccountController.cs
- CartController.cs
- FormController.cs

I assume default.aspx is the first file it hits, but then what happens after that?

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods possible, maybe one of those fits:

Define a Startpage in IIS Manager:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320051/how-to-configure-the-default-document-in-internet-information-services

Define a Startpage in your web.xml file:

```
<configuration> 
<system.webServer> 
    <defaultDocument enabled="true"> 
        <files> 
            <add value="home.cshtml" /> 
        </files> 
    </defaultDocument> 
</system.webServer>
```

Have a RouteConfig class ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)):

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Listen to Sessionstart:

[How can I define a start page in my ASP.NET website (IIS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415913/how-can-i-define-a-start-page-in-my-asp-net-website-iis)

There are probably even more options