# Why do we see a default IIS page on a system where iis is enabled when we enter a public IP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

I am navigating to my public Ip.On that ip/system IIS is running.By default we i get the IIS start page though I have no hosted website in inetpub/wwwrooot.What is the reason for this?

Comment: please set default page in IIS and fellow below Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208381/how-do-i-set-the-default-page-of-my-application-in-iis7

Comment: Because of the default configuration of IIS?

Answer (score 3):

Open the IIS. Navigate to Sites > Default Web Site. As shown in this image: https://gyazo.com/fd237a8c74e66c15ff1d9773db7c587a

Open Default Documents, you will see the list of files that IIS will look into wwwRoot folder and display that file content. iisstart.htm is one of them and htm/html page don't need any specific tool to run.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check If there is a default website running? It is probably running some sort of a default website.