# Website homepage error, but Default.aspx is working

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, umbraco

I have an Umbraco Website hosted. This site was working fine. But from few months we cannot access the website homepage.

- www.MySite.com ERROR
- www.MySite.com/default.aspx WORKING
- www.MySite.com/team WORKING

Im getting 404 error and its looking for a **\index.html.var**
in the physical folder.

[image]

Comment: did you get a chance to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208381/how-do-i-set-the-default-page-of-my-application-in-iis7

Comment: Yes I did, but it didnt work as well. This site was hosted like 1 year ago. From last month only I'm getting this error

Comment: Requested URL    http://example.com:80/index.html.var

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could follow below way to find out the reason.

1.Check the web.config to make sure you don't have the url rewrite rule. Like below:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite"  stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://xxxxxx.com/index.html.var" 
redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

2.Check you don't have some special default document setting, you could open the IIS manager as below image shows:

[image]

[image]

3.If you don't have some special setting in IIS and web.config, I suggest you could follow below article to reset the default page:

http://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/umbraco-core-concepts/how-to-set-the-start-page-in-umbraco-7

Comment: 1.I checked, but I coudnt find any with index.html.var

Comment: 3. I did and check no use