# MS Visual Studio 2017 problem with ASPX publishing a website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I'm quite new in ASPX development, as I was a desktop application developer for the past 18 years.

I am creating this ASPX / VB.NET application and when I build it and run it shows all the changes I did without any problem, but when I publish it shows the results in the attached picture.

[image]

Could you please help me by guiding me in the right settings and I will be very much appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be that your "home" page does not have the same name as the currently-set default page in IIS. [How do I set the default page of my application in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4208381/1115360)

Comment: Hi @Andrew Morton, I did the settings on IIS (with the help of the IT Admin) and nothing changed. Thanks

Comment: OK, perhaps you will have more luck with [How to deploy an ASP.NET Web application using Xcopy deployment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/326355/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-web-application-using-xcopy-deployment). Which is basically copy-and-paste the files to the correct directory on the web server.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Morton, Thanks again for your reply, but I tried that before I post this question here. I think is something wrong in the VS settings somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I used the "Single Page Project" template to create the starting project then I modified it and add/changed the logic of the web app.

Comment: 1) If you create a "Hello World" HTML page, does that get served correctly? 2) Can you check the file modification date of your .aspx page and see if it is the same as the one on your local computer?

Comment: I don't know what I did, but it says that "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Comment: I published Hello World webapp and it works, then when I do change the code to say Hello World 2 it still shows Hello World.

Comment: The dates on the published files are all updated and it's the same as my computer.

Comment: Did you use IIS on your local computer? If not (for example, you might have used IIS Express), have a go at making it work with IIS. Otherwise, I suggest installing [Windows Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016) from the ISO in a Hyper-V machine on your computer and playing around with installing your website on that to investigate where the correct settings are.

Comment: Hi Andrew, we don't have a license for Win 2016, but I tried to delete the IIS site and recreate it from scratch and uploaded the code and followed your first answer and it works fine now. Don't know what causes the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the evaluation version, it's free for 180 days. Whereupon you can make a new VM for another 180 days. The intention is only to have something local to mess around with ("evaluate configurations") before changing something on the actual web server. Anyway, glad to read that you persuaded it to work :)

Comment: Can you show me the web.config settings of your iis? and do you have any default routes set in your RouteConfig or other place.

Answer (score -1):

You are running the application from IIS? Set default page to view to your required page.

Comment: Yes, I did and nothing changed. Thanks.