# Unable to uninstall IIS 10 from windows server 2016 Datacenter

Tags: windows-server-2016, iis-10

[image]

I am getting below error while trying to uninstall IIS 10, am using windows server 2016 . Please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/installation-issues/troubleshooting-iis-7x-installation-issues Get started from there please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

Run PowerShell as administrator and type the next command.

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online | ? featurename -like "IIS" | Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -Remove
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, IIS got installed but localhost default page is not launching.

Comment: Take a look at how to set default page for your application: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208381/how-do-i-set-the-default-page-of-my-application-in-iis7

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after updating the visual c++ packages.