# Angular9 Application Deployment on IIS - Throws Access Denied issue

Tags: javascript, angular, iis

we have hosted angular 9 application on IIS . When we browse the application from IIS like below
https://localhost/xaportal
it gives  the " access denied issue -403"

when  we try to change the browser URL  like https://localhost/xaportal/index.html - it is working fine and load all the components required.

we tried "URL  rewriting" concept for angular in web.config. but that doesn't work. Where we can set the default routing in angular to redirect to index.html.

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your configuration in IIS, not Angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default page of my application in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208381/how-do-i-set-the-default-page-of-my-application-in-iis7)